# Can we read text from the selected objects in perception simulation

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I am automating the hololense application using perception simulation. In one of the scenario, I need to perform click action on the specific objects based on the name.So, Is it possible to read the text of the selected objects ? (Note: I have selected the objects using right hand /light hand move and object is selected with distinguished color )

Comment: Could you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve? Is the "object" you mentioned a hologram? Or it from the real world?  Based on what you said it needs to read text, I guess the function you need is like text to speech.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT: It is a hologram and we can able to see the multiple folders virtually. I am able to select the folders by moving the hand .But, I need to select the correct folders based on Text. ( Note: I am trying this via script )

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to build test automation for your app or file explorer base on the Hololens2 emulator. And what your requirement is making it automatically tap an object with a matching name in the emulator.

If so, the emulator does not support the feature which recognizing text or direct returning data from the application memory. However, you can provide more information about your business request and submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens2 emulator.

For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app)

Out of the field of HoloLens app development, you can code your own desktop program to capture the view in the emulator window, and then use OCR technology to recognize the character in the screen. Finally, customize your input to the simulator according to the result. However, this is not a simple way.

Comment: Thank you !!! I will send the feedback to the Microsoft